# My ledger says I have 19 direct vassals but the upper-right corner says I have 10 vassals

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I think that my vassals often control provinces outside my realm, but I have trouble understanding the upper-right corner. It says I have 10 vassals, but maybe it means only 10 vassals with big desmesnes. Or maybe 10 of my vassals are inside my realm but the other 9 are outside my realm.

Basic question: why doesn't my vassal limit match my ledger?

Advanced question: My character portrait has a "realm tree" button. It displays direct vassals.

Postscript:

The interface for Crusader Kings II is a bit challenging. It is difficult to look at the map and understand which provinces are part of my realm.  I would expect to find a tree structure (where I can see multiple levels and controlled provinces).  In fact, it seems I have to select all my vassals in turn and try to locate their holdings on the map. (It seems I can only see the controlled provinces for one duke at a time. I would prefer to be able to see all the provinces in my realm, color-coded according to duke.)

I know that I can click on a province to get information about it. However, that tends to lead me astray into confusing connections.  The realm map (activated by the lower-right-hand menu set) often uses almost exactly the same color for my country and its enemies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vassal-count in the upper right corner only shows direct vassals, which are count-level or above. If you yourself control a county (which you have to, otherwise it would be a game over) it is most likely that in that county a temple , city or barony exists, which you do not control yourself. They are technically your direct vassals but do not count against your vassal limit.

CK2-Wiki for further reading: https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Vassals#Direct_vassal_limits

About your second question: If you change into the realm-view (i believe its called, just press W while in game) all the independent realms should be shown. If you now hold CTRL and Left-Click into your own realm, your realm will be split by the direct vassals. With this you can better grasp how, geographically, your realm is split.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to add something: You can also have a barony under your county (a feudal county capital is just a barony anyway), and it's ruler (the baron) also doesn't count towards the vassal limit. Furthermore, all titles are variations of baron, count, duke, king, emperor. A better way to put it is that all baron or lower (unlanded) vassals do not count towards the limit.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i left that out, because it's generally a rare occasion, but i edited in to reflect that.

Comment: It's not actually that rare either I build baronies all the time to give people with claims I want to press land so they will remain my vassals.